# Letter grade function

Tags: python, new-operator

I'm very new to python, I need to write a function that takes a letter grade (a,b,c,d,f, possibly with a + or -) and returns a number grade. The values are 4,3,2,1,0. So an A would be a 4.0, and B would be 3.0. An A+ would increase the number grade value by 0.3 and A- decreases the number grade by 0.3. Upper and lowercase ones are supposed to be able to be used. Some examples.

```
>>> letter2number('A-')
3.7

>>> letter2number('B+')
3.3

>>> letter2number('D')
1.0

>>> letter2number('a+')
4.3
```

I do not know where to start with this coding, and I've been on the search everywhere for some helpful code.

Comment: use dict to store mappings between A-D+- and problem becomes a simple condition.

Comment: Have you been through a Python tutorial to learn the basics of the language? If not then go through one and pay particular attention to conditionals and string manipulation.

Answer (score 5):

Python has something called dictionaries. These are able to take a value (called the "key") and return a value associated with that key. This is just like looking up the definition of something in a dictionary.

For instance:

```
test = { 'a': 4.0, 'b': 3.0 }
```

The above creates a dictionary that associates the value 4.0 with the key "a", and 3.0 with the key "b". You use the `[]` operator to look up values:

```
print test["a"]
4.0
```

It should be obvious how this can be extended to implement all of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Here's a few pointers:

You can brute-force this. A dictionary could hold all possible letter codes as keys and grades as values:

```
mygrades = {"a+": 4.3, "a": 4.0, "a-": 3.7 }    # etc.
```

You'd have to transform your input into lowercase so it won't fail on "A+". And you would want to use a `try...except KeyError:` block to catch illegal arguments.

It would be a bit nicer if you made the whole thing more customizable. For example, you could define `best = 4.0, worst= 1.0, step = -1.0, between = 0.3` and calculate the result by looking at the first character of your argument, checking if there's a `+` or `-` following that, and adding all that together.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> grades = {'a':4, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':1, '+':0.3, '-':-0.3}
>>> sum([grades[x.lower()] for x in 'c+'])
2.3
>>> sum([grades[x.lower()] for x in 'D-'])
0.7
>>> sum([grades[x.lower()] for x in 'A+'])
4.3
```

Since this is homework: to figure out how it works and changing it so that it is a function left as exercise :)

this does NOT validate whether the grade is syntactically correct, but will also work with 'grades' `aBBa`, `-B+C` and `A++++`